# Indexing a 2D List with another List

Tags: python, list, indexing

If I have a `list` such as:

```
lst = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

and another `list` which contains a `[row, column]` `index` for an element in the `list`, so for example:

```
index = [2, 1]
```

Obviously I can get the `element` at `index` with:

```
lst[index[0]][index[1]]
```

However,  I find that this `syntax` is quite clunky and doesn't sit well in a big block of code. It would also become worse with a higher dimensional `list`.

My question: **is there an easier way to do this `index`?**

It would seem that something like:

```
lst[index]
```

would be more readable but this isn't how Python works so isn't an option.

Comment: you can do `i, j = index` then `lst[i][j]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with a 2D-list, it might be a good idea to use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/). You'll then simply need to define [`index` as a tuple](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#dealing-with-variable-numbers-of-indices-within-programs). Index `3` would be out of range, though:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> index = (1, 2)
>>> a[index]
6
```

The method you're looking for is called [`Array#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Array.html#method-i-dig) in Ruby:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]].dig(1, 2)
# 6
```

but I couldn't find any plain Python equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You could just create a simple function that iterates over the index. For every element in index just fetch item from object and assign that as a new object. Once you have iterated over the whole index return current object. As @EricDuminil noted it works with dicts and all other objects that support [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

```
def index(obj, idx):
    for i in idx:
        obj = obj[i]

    return obj

LST = [[1,2,3], [4,[5],6], [{'foo': {'bar': 'foobar'}},8,9]]
INDEXES = [[2, 2], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 'foo', 'bar']]

for i in INDEXES:
    print('{0} -> {1}'.format(i, index(LST, i)))
```

Output:

```
[2, 2] -> 9
[1, 1, 0] -> 5
[2, 0, 'foo', 'bar'] -> foobar
```

Comment: +1 Nice neat function - especially for being able to work for `n` dimensions. However, I find the `numpy` solution is neater in my opinion!

Comment: Nice. As a bonus, it also works (if you're careful) with dicts. `[[1,2,3], [4,[5],6], [7,8,9, {'a':'b'}]]` and `index(lst, [2, 3, 'a'])`.

Answer (score 1):

The method you used is probably the simplest way, but for better readability you could go for something like

```
i = index[0]
j = index[1]
x = lst[i][j]
```

One way or another, you need to split your index list into the 2 values. If you want to declutter your main block of code, you can write a function to handle this, but that would hardly be "easier".

EDIT: As suggested below, tuple unpacking is an even better option

```
i, j = index
x = lst[i][j]
```

Comment: Or, using tuple unpacking, `i, j = index` /  `x = lst[i][j]`.